# How to read the result of a Radiobutton with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to add some widgets like Radiobutton with Python2.7 but my code does not compile. What I want is mainly when I click on IN or OUT is to display the result of `radio.on_clicked(sel)`. This is my code :

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons
import os
import Tkinter as tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from tkFileDialog import asksaveasfile
import ntpath
from Tkinter import Label
from Tkinter import Listbox
from Tkinter import END
import Tix
import scipy

class Index(object):
    ind = 0

    def pre(self, event):
        print radio.on_clicked(sel) 

callback = Index()

axplot = plt.axes([0.11,0.92,0.08,0.07])
bplot = Button(axplot, 'Plot')
bplot.on_clicked(callback.pre)

choice = plt.axes([0.44,0.92,0.08,0.07])
radio = RadioButtons(choice, ('IN', 'OUT'))
def sel(var):
    if var == "IN":
        print "IN"
        return True
    elif var == "OUT":
        print "OUT"
        return False

plt.show()
```

But when I click on the Radiobutton I see nothing in the console. And also I want to keep the class Index to do this.

Thank you a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The line `print radio.on_clicked(sel)` does not make any sense at all.
`radio.on_clicked(sel)` registers a callback in the matplotlib callback registry and returns the number of this callback in the register. So the first time you call it, it may return 1, second time 2 etc. The more often you do it, the more of the same callbacks you end up having in the callback registry, whereas one of them is enough.

It could be that the following is doing what you need.

```
import pylab as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons

def sel(var):
    if var == "IN":
        print "IN"
        return True
    elif var == "OUT":
        print "OUT"
        return False

def pre(event):
    print "You clicked the button"

axplot = plt.axes([0.11,0.92,0.08,0.07])
bplot = Button(axplot, 'Plot')
bplot.on_clicked(pre)

choice = plt.axes([0.44,0.92,0.08,0.07])
radio = RadioButtons(choice, ('IN', 'OUT'))
radio.on_clicked(sel)

plt.show()
```