# Radiobutton does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Hello I created a script python which allows to draw a polygon. Actually I have some points and what I want is this: I draw a polygon and the points which are inside are removed and the others are kept. But I created a `RadioButton` to do the reverse that is to say the points which are outside are removed and the others are kept.

This is my code but it does not work because of `RadioButton`:

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons
import os
import Tkinter as tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from tkFileDialog import asksaveasfile
import ntpath
from Tkinter import Label
from Tkinter import Listbox
from Tkinter import END
import Tix
import scipy

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
b = np.sin(a)
c = plt.plot(a,b,'r.')

cd = np.array([])

class Index(object):
    ind = 0



callback = Index()

choice = plt.axes([0.0, 0.92, 0.08, 0.07])
radio = RadioButtons(choice, ('IN', 'OUT'))
def sel(var):
    if var == "IN":

        return True
    elif var == "OUT":

        return False

class Canvas(object):

    def __init__(self,ax):

        self.ax = ax
        self.azer = radio.on_clicked(sel)

        self.path, = ax.plot([],[],'o-',lw=3)
        self.vert = []

        self.x = [] 
        self.y = []

        self.mouse_button = {1: self._add_point, 2: self._delete_point, 3: self._close_polygon}

    def set_location(self,event):
        if event.inaxes:
            self.x = event.xdata
            self.y = event.ydata

    def _add_point(self):

        self.vert.append((self.x,self.y))

    def _delete_point(self):
        if len(self.vert)>0:
            self.vert.pop()

    def _close_polygon(self):
        global a,b,c
        if radio.on_clicked(sel) == True:

            self.vert.append(self.vert[0])
            myList=[]
            for i in range(0,a.size):
                myList.append(Point(float(a[i]),float(b[i])))
                polygon = Polygon(self.vert)
            for i1 in range(0,len(a)):
                if not polygon.contains(myList[i1]):
                    q = i1 
                    a = np.delete(a,q-(len(myList)-len(a)))
                    b = np.delete(b,q-(len(myList)-len(b)))
                    c[0].remove()
                    c = ax.plot(a,b, 'r.')
            for i2 in range(0,len(self.vert)):
                self.vert.pop()
        elif radio.on_clicked(sel) == False:

            self.vert.append(self.vert[0])
            myList=[]
            for i in range(0,a.size):
                myList.append(Point(float(a[i]),float(b[i])))
                polygon = Polygon(self.vert)
            for i1 in range(0,len(a)):
                if polygon.contains(myList[i1]):
                    q = i1 
                    a = np.delete(a,q-(len(myList)-len(a)))
                    b = np.delete(b,q-(len(myList)-len(b)))
                    c[0].remove()
                    c = ax.plot(a,b, 'r.')
            for i2 in range(0,len(self.vert)):
                self.vert.pop()   

    def update_path(self,event):

        if event.inaxes!=self.ax: return 

        self.mouse_button[event.button]()

        x = [self.vert[k][0] for k in range(len(self.vert))]
        y = [self.vert[k][1] for k in range(len(self.vert))]
        self.path.set_data(x,y)
        plt.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    fig = plt.figure(1,(8,8))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    cnv = Canvas(ax)

    plt.connect('button_press_event',cnv.update_path)
    plt.connect('motion_notify_event',cnv.set_location)


plt.show()
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Actually when i do this : print radio.on_clicked(sel) i get some number like 1,4,7,... instead of True or False i think this is the problem but i don't know how to solve it :/

Comment: `radio.on_clicked(sel)` returns the index of the callback. I.e. the first callback you register in you code gets index 0, and so on. So this is definitely not what you want. It's therefore crucial to describe more in detail what you would expect instead. You might want to team up with @AndreBostwick, it seem you both have [similar problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815560/how-to-read-the-result-of-a-radiobutton-with-python).

Comment: Ok thank you yes it is not what i want. Actually i want to get the result of the Radiobutton that is to say if it is "IN" or "OUT" and put the result in this function  _close_polygon(self)

Comment: The current state of the radio button can be accessed via `radio.value_selected`.